# Example tripped Kolmogorov and Wiener

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

[image]

---

Assuming the hint is true, I attempt to prove the latter prop:

Assume on the contrary that $\mathscr{L} = \mathscr{R}$.

If $\sigma(Y_0) \subseteq \mathscr{L}$, then $\sigma(Y_0) \subseteq \mathscr{R}$.

Since $\sigma(Y_0)$ and $\mathscr{R}$ are independent, $\sigma(Y_0)$ is independent of itself.

This means $\forall F \in \sigma(Y_0), P(F \cap F) = P(F)P(F) \ \to \ P(F) \in \{0,1\}$.

Choose $F = (Y_0 = 1)$ or $F = (Y_0 = -1)$. We have $P(F) = 1/2 \notin \{0,1\}$

Is that right? I based it off the [K 0-1 Law proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303735/questions-on-kolmogorov-zero-one-law-proof-in-williams).

Comment: Is $\sigma(\cal Y, T_n)$ the same thing as $\sigma(\cal Y \cup T_n)$? I don't understand what the comma means.

Comment: @Shalop Um, like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476735/elements-in-sigma-algebra-generated-by-sets-a-b)?

Comment: @Shalop Anyway, I think understanding $\mathscr{L}$ and $\mathscr{R}$ is relevant for proving the hint rather than assuming the hint and then proving the second statement

Comment: Explain downvote?

Comment: Do you want a proof of the hint? I thought that you just wanted someone to check what you wrote above, i.e, that the event $\{Y_0=1\}$ is in $\cal L \backslash R$, which is true. BTW, I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: @Shalop I didn't tag you in my 'Explain downvote?' comment :P I don't yet want proof of the hint. I am attempting to prove it myself. I do want a proof check (hence the proof-verification tag). What do you mean such event is in $\mathscr{L}$ \ $\mathscr{R}$ ? An event in the empty set has undefined rather than zero probability?

Comment: I mean that the event $\{Y_0=1\}$ is in $\cal L$ but not in $\cal R$. Actually your proof (together with the hint) shows that.

Comment: @Shalop Um, so the proof is right?

Comment: Yeah, it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it looks fine to me. –  Shalop Jul 16 at 23:11