# Find sigma-algebra of particular set.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$. Specify the $\Theta=\left \{ \left \{ 4 \right \} ,2\mathbb{N}+1\right \}$ generated by $\sigma$-Algebra. where the set $2\mathbb{N}+1=\left \{ 2n+1 | n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$ refers to all odd.

$\sigma(\Theta)=\{\{4\},\mathbb{N},2n+1,2n \setminus 4\}$

Is this right?

Comment: ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476735/elements-in-sigma-algebra-generated-by-sets-a-b

Comment: Try putting a slash before the { or }