# Field and sigma algebra generated by a set

Tags: analysis, field-theory

I'm trying to figure out why is this construction:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477330

the field generated by a set?

Can someone give an example or explain?

Comment: Are you referring to the construction in the accepted answer?

Comment: No, the answer of Abishanka Saha, the "general methodology"